# Alternative to Gwibber with message indicator support

Tags: 13.04, indicator, gwibber, friends-app, indicator-message

On Ubuntu 13.04 it's impossibile to install Gwibber, you get Friends-app instead. This one lacks of message indicator support, can you suggest me an alternative to Gwibber with this function?

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin is an easy to use and free chat client used by millions. Connect to AIM, MSN, Yahoo, and more chat networks all at once.

To install Pidgin just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```

Comment: I know Pidgin and it's not what I need, I just want a twitter client with indicator-messages and notify osd support.

Comment: Then you may want to look at [this](http://onlireeks.netne.net/node/11).